# Gson deserialization for a list in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

This is what my json looks like

```
{
  "sub": "9",

  "auth_time": 1559381757,
  "idp": "idsrv",

  "role": [
    "Employer",
    "Employee",
    "Student"
  ],


  "iss": "",
  "aud": "",
  "exp": 1574933757,
  "nbf": 1559381757
}
```

This is the object I want to convert this Json into.

```
data class Claims (
    @SerializedName("nameid") val nameId: String,
    @SerializedName("unique_id") val uniqueId: String,
    @SerializedName("sub") val sub: String,
    @SerializedName("unifiedNumber") val unifiedNumber: String,
    @SerializedName("role") var roleList: List<Role>
)
```

I wrote a custom Deserializer (which works in Java) for the List type

```
class RoleDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<List<Role>> {

    private var roleId = 0
    @Throws(JsonParseException::class)
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): MutableList<Role> {
        val resultList = ArrayList<Role>()
        if (json.isJsonArray) {
            for (e in json.asJsonArray) {
                resultList.add(Role(id = roleId++, name = e.asString))
            }
        } else if (json.isJsonObject) {
            resultList.add(Role(id = roleId++, name = json.asString))
        } else if (json.isJsonPrimitive) {
            if ((json as JsonPrimitive).isString)
                resultList.add(Role(id = roleId++, name = json.getAsString()))
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException("Unexpected JSON type: " + json.javaClass)
        }
        return resultList
    }
}
```

This is how I register my type adapter

```
val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<List<Role>>() {}.type
        val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(listType, RoleDeserializer()).create()
        val claims = gson.fromJson(stringJson, Claims::class.java)
```

I still get a parse exception stating that

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 161 path $.role[0]
```

and my RoleDeserializer is never called. Am I doing something wrong while registering the type adapter?

Comment: The exception says it's expecting an object but found a string when parsing the first item of the `role` array. That is because you defined `role` as a `List<Role>` while it should have been a `List<String>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<List<Role>>() {}.type
```

with

```
val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<MutableList<Role>>() {}.type
```

Answer (score 0):

The `role` is String array in `JSON`

Use this

```
@SerializedName("role") var roleList: List<String>
```

Instead of this

```
@SerializedName("role") var roleList: List<Role>
```

Try this

```
data class Claims (
    @SerializedName("nameid") val nameId: String,
    @SerializedName("unique_id") val uniqueId: String,
    @SerializedName("sub") val sub: String,
    @SerializedName("unifiedNumber") val unifiedNumber: String,
    @SerializedName("role") var roleList: List<String>
)
```

Comment: Nilesh . This is actually what I need to do . I need to convert the role Property of the JSON not into a list of strings , but into a list of Roles . 

That is why i wrote the deserializer. I just copy pasted this from Java to kotlin and it stopped working

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib can u share your `Role` class with question